# function takes iterabls and return a list

Tags: python, iterable

```
def group_when(iterable,p):
    x = iter(iterable)
    z = []
    d = []
    try:
        while True:
            y = next(x)
            if p(y) == False:
                z.append(y)
            elif p(y) == True:
                z.append(y)
                d.append(z) 
                z = []
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return
```

The group_when generator takes one iterable and one predicate as parameters: it produces lists that each end in a value from the iterable where the predicate is True. If the iterable ends on a value for which the predicate returns False, yield a final list containing all the values from the one after the previous end to the last value produced by the iterable

for example:

```
for i in group_when('combustibles', lambda x : x in 'aeiou'):
    print(i,end='')
```

prints the 5 lists ['c', 'o']['m', 'b', 'u']['s', 't', 'i']['b', 'l', 'e']['s'].

my function is getting so close to the correct answer. when the input is

```
('combustibles', lambda x : x in 'aeiou')
```

my function returns

```
[['c', 'o'], ['m', 'b', 'u'], ['s', 't', 'i'], ['b', 'l', 'e']]
```

but the correct output should be:

```
[['c', 'o'], ['m', 'b', 'u'], ['s', 't', 'i'], ['b', 'l', 'e'], ['s']]
```

Therefore, I am only missing the last letter 's'. 
can anyone tell me how to fix it? many thanks

I posted the error I got below just to help you to understand my function:

```
 26 *Error: Failed [v for v in group_when('combustibles', lambda x : x in 'aeiou')] == [['c', 'o'], ['m', 'b', 'u'], ['s', 't', 'i'], ['b', 'l', 'e'], ['s']]
      evaluated: [['c', 'o'], ['m', 'b', 'u'], ['s', 't', 'i'], ['b', 'l', 'e']] == [['c', 'o'], ['m', 'b', 'u'], ['s', 't', 'i'], ['b', 'l', 'e'], ['s']]
 27 *Error: Failed [v for v in group_when(hide('combustibles'), lambda x : x in 'aeiou')] == [['c', 'o'], ['m', 'b', 'u'], ['s', 't', 'i'], ['b', 'l', 'e'], ['s']]
      evaluated: [['c', 'o'], ['m', 'b', 'u'], ['s', 't', 'i'], ['b', 'l', 'e']] == [['c', 'o'], ['m', 'b', 'u'], ['s', 't', 'i'], ['b', 'l', 'e'], ['s']]
```

Comment: instead of `while` use `for`-loop. Call `p(y)` only once.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but don't you need a last d.append(z)?

Comment: plus this isn't really a generator right?  for it to be a generator it should be using `yield`.  I'm certainly not an expert on them, but I thought that was always the case.

Comment: @bravosierra99  by last, you mean where?

Comment: @Daniel I am not really sure how to do it by using for loop, something like for x in iter(iterable) ?  can you show my an example ?

Comment: @zhangdi   So you append your last list ['b','l','e'] to `d`  Then you start your loop again, and you are on 's'.  `p('s')` returns false so you 'z.append(y)`.  then your loop starts again and you get your `StopIteration`.  `z` never get's appended to `d`

Comment: @zhangdi look at xZise's answer.  Thats what I was trying to say.

Comment: Your code wont work. I don't see anything being returned or being yielded from your code.

Comment: @zhangdi Also this is not at all a generator method. Its just a simple method. You might want to look at my answer to check out the generator version of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So going with your original form, this is how I would fix your issue.

```
def group_when(iterable,p):
    x = iter(iterable)
    z = []
    d = []
    for y in x:
        z.append(y)
        if p(y):
            d.append(z) 
            z = []
    if z:
        d.append(z) 
    return d   #added the d here, think OP dropped it by accident
```

Comment: you are welcome!  And thank you for accepting the answer.  Though I will tell you that this does not appear to be a generator, and could easily be turned into one!  You might look into doing that with the `yield` command.  You could `yield z` in place of `d.append(z)` and I believe it would work as a generator.

Comment: @bravosierra99 Where are you returning the values ? Am i missing something ?

Comment: no, I have no idea at all @Shasha99 !!  but he wasn't returning the values in his code so I didn't want to get too involved in what is going on here.  I just fixed the issue he was having.  But you are correct, I have no idea how he's getting the values out.  unless his code ends with `return d` and the `d` got cut off.....

Comment: Also do we really need if p(y)==False ? This can be a little cleaner as i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: i've applied all the changes I would apply now if I had written the code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you only add `z` to `d` if you get a predicate. So if the string doesn't end with a predicate it won't add `z` one last time. So you need at the end somewhere:

```
if z:
    d.append(z)
```

This adds `z` only if it is not empty. But your code is missing `yield` or the actual `return` statement so I'm not sure where this should happen.

Also you don't need to directly compare it to the booleans. In fact you could do the following:

```
if p(y):
    z.append(y)
    d.append(z)
    z = []
else:
    z.append(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You code will give incorrect result when the predicate returns **False** for last element in iterator.

z wont be appended to d if p(y) is False for last y in iterable.  You should handle that case.

Extend your code and add 2 more lines after except as mentioned below:

```
except StopIteration:
        pass
if len(z) !=0:
    y.append(z)
```

---

You may use the following code doing the same work:

```
def group_when(iterable,p):
    z = []
    d = []

    for y in iterable:
        z.append(y)
        if p(y) is True:
            d.append(z)
            z=[]
    if z:
        d.append(z)
    return d
```

---

Following is the generator version of your code:

```
def group_when(iterable,p):
    z = []
    for y in iterable:
        z.append(y)
        if p(y) is True:
            yield z
            z=[]
    if z :
        yield z
    return
```

Comment: not a bad solution, but the `len(z)` is unnecessary.  `if z:` returns `False` if it's the empty list `[]`

Comment: yea I see you added the `d`  I bet that's what his code actually has...

Comment: @bravosierra99, Yes you are correct. No need for len()